# Notable to access application outside the Azure remote desktop

Tags: azure

I have created virtual machine in Azure cloud and connected to it using remote desktop, installed IIS in it and copy pasted XAP file from my desktop to remote and configured in IIS, i can able to browse application in remote but it cannot be accessed in my local desktop or out of remote, any ideas would be appreciated..

Tnx..

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop cannot route network traffic to your VM.

In your case I would suggest you to use a Point-to-Site (P2S) connection to access your website.

For that reason you have to create a virtual network in Azure, deploy your VM into that virtual network and use P2S to connect to your virtual network via VPN. After that you can access your VM's webserver from your local computer.

Here you find a step-by-step guide how to do this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/

By the way, you cannot move an existing VM into a virtual network. But there is a very easy workaround. Delete your VM, but DO NOT delete the associated disks or VHDs. Then create a new VM and select in the creation wizard to use an existing disk. There you select the disk from your just deleted VM.

[image: Create VM form gallery]